# Adding SCNNode to GPS Coordinates

Tags: swift, gps, scenekit, arkit

I am trying to place a node at GPS coordinates using the MatrixHelper function from this open source project: https://github.com/chriswebb09/ARKitNavigationDemo but when I run the app, it prints "added sphereNode at (xyz coordinates)" which proves it's getting through the code all the way, but the spheres are not added. I tried adjusting the size of the spheres thinking that maybe they were too far away to see, but changing the radius doesnt help.

Here's the function that adds the spheres:

```
func repositionTarget(stepLocation: CLLocation) {
        let locationTransform = MatrixHelper.transformMatrix(for: matrix_identity_float4x4, originLocation: userLoc!, location: stepLocation)
        let stepAnchor = ARAnchor(transform: locationTransform)
        let sphere = SphereNode(location: stepLocation)
        sphere.addSphere(with: 3.5, and: .blue)
        sphere.location = stepLocation
        sphere.anchor = stepAnchor
        sphere.position = SCNVector3(stepAnchor.transform.columns.3.x, 0, stepAnchor.transform.columns.3.z)
        sceneView.session.add(anchor: stepAnchor)
        sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(sphere)
        print("added sphereNode at", sphere.position)
}
```

and here is my SphereNode:

```
import Foundation
import SceneKit
import UIKit
import ARKit
import CoreLocation

class SphereNode: SCNNode {

    var anchor: ARAnchor?
    var location: CLLocation!

    init(location: CLLocation) {
        super.init()
        let billboardConstraint = SCNBillboardConstraint()
        billboardConstraint.freeAxes = SCNBillboardAxis.Y
        constraints = [billboardConstraint]
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func createSphereNode(with radius: CGFloat, color: UIColor) -> SCNNode {
        let geometry = SCNSphere(radius: radius)
        geometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = color
        let sphereNode = SCNNode(geometry: geometry)
        return sphereNode
    }

    func addSphere(with radius: CGFloat, and color: UIColor) {
        let sphereNode = createSphereNode(with: radius, color: color)
        addChildNode(sphereNode)
    }
}
```

The MatrixHelper I'm using is found here: https://github.com/chriswebb09/ARKitNavigationDemo/blob/master/ARKitNavigationDemo/ARKitNavigationDemo/Services/Helpers/MatrixHelper.swift

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Can anyone see where I'm going wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Did you get any solution?